# explain() is not a function

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Using MongoDB v3.0.3. Ran into a problem with running db.grades.explain().find() - I keep getting the message "TypeError: db.grades.explain is not a function (shell):1"

I can, however, use db.grades.find().explain() - but the information returned using this method isn't as helpful as collection.explain()

Comment: Robomongo is running way behind compatibilty with the MongoDB shell. It is still based on builds from the MongoDB 2.4.x series and uses the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine still. In MongoDB 2.6 builds and above the engine is V8, and much of the integration logic has changed. There are plenty of posts mentioning the incompatibilties of current MongoDB shell releases compared to RoboMongo.

Comment: Official line to follow: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/520

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, this was because I was using Robomongo (ver 0.8.5) I just assumed that everything you could do in the shell, you could do in Robomongo, but apparently not. When I switched over to using the command line, db.collection.explain() worked just fine.